# Changing system default graphics card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I'm currently using Ubuntu 22.04 in my notebook Lenovo Gaming 15AH05, with no extra monitors. Recently I installed the Nvidia drivers and when I run the command 'nvidia-smi' this is the output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 525.85.05    Driver Version: 525.85.05    CUDA Version: 12.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   45C    P8     3W /  50W |      6MiB /  4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                           
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      2505      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I also created a pretty default xorg.conf file using the command 'nvidia-xconfig' creating this result:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 525.85.05

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

And this is the result of the command 'lspci | grep VGA':

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c6)
```

Now, when I access **Settings > Details > Graphics** it says: 'NVIDIA Corporation TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile] / RENOIR (renoir, LLVM 15.0.6, DRM 3.47, 5.19.0-35-generic)'

So I can tell it's being recognized, but when I access a videogame (Factorio in this case) and modify the sprite graphic quality to 'High' it says 'We've detected that your graphics card only has 512mb of memory...' (Even when I try to run it with **Right click > Run with dedicated graphics card**)

So I'm wondering if there's a way to properly set the xorg.conf file to make my dedicated graphics card the system's default graphics card, or perhaps a better approach to this situation that would serve as a better fix.

Comment: Try to take a look at the following blog post: [https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu](https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu)

Comment: WIll most certainly do, thank you! Now I just need fix an issue with my drivers, between I asked the question until now, my GPU is no longer being recognized.